# std::this_thread::sleep_for() vs sleep() in main()

Tags: c++, c++11, sleep, stdthread, usleep

std::this_thread::sleep_for() Or usleep()

What would be better to be used in main()? This may be very silly but i am new to C++11 features.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The former is actually a portable C++ function. The latter is an obsolete, non-portable POSIX function (replaced by `nanosleep`, which remains non-portable). Use `std::this_thread::sleep_for()`, which will likely be implemented in terms of `nanosleep` when available/appropriate, or whatever other function the system provides otherwise.